# How to use '\cfrac' in IPE instead of '\frac'?

Tags: ipe

I just started using IPE and I like it a lot, but in my formula's I always use '\cfrac' instead of '\frac' but the IPE Latex compiler gives me an error when I use it.

The compiler error I get is quite long but the digest is at the bottom with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \cfrac
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You write, "...the IPE Latex compiler gives me an error". Please tell us more about the error message you're getting.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Loaded package `amsmath` that provides `\cfrac`?

Comment: Great that makes it work!

Comment: Note that the failure to load the `amsmath` package is quite unrelated to whether or not you employ IPE.

Comment: Yes I understand, I am used using editors where you can do inline math, e.g. Obsidian, and there its not required.
Thank you all for the quick help!